# TensorFlow neural network regression model stuck at linear

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm building a TensorFlow neural network model to do a regression fit on some data. Ultimately my data will be many-dimensional, but I'm working out the kinks with a 1D case. The 1D data can be seen in the figure below. The trouble I'm having is that the NN is fitting a line to the data, when the data is non-linear, and no matter what I do to the model specification I don't seem to be able to change that behavior.

The code for my model (TensorFlow 2.4) look like this:

```
    # 1D Linear model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_dim=1),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
        layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(units=1)])

    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=1e0,
        decay_steps=50,
        decay_rate=0.2)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule), loss='mse')
    history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs = 200, validation_split = 0.2, verbose = 0)
```

The training history looks like this, so it's clearly learning up to a point:
[image: img description]

The result is pretty clearly a linear model trying to fit the data:

[image]

I thought having a nonlinear activation function in the earlier layers would do the trick and get a nonlinear curve fit. Things I've tried: changing number of layers and units in layer, adding/removing dropouts, changing activation functions among `relu`, `sigmoid`, `tanh`, etc., changing learning rate (constant or decaying schedule)...none of these produce the behavior I'm looking for.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to the TF model to make it go nonlinear and fit a curve to this data?

Comment: The initial lr is 1?

Comment: Yes, the initial lr is 1. This speeds the model's convergence.